# notify-send not working under Flashback

Tags: notification, notify-osd

Unable to send messages with `notify-send` under Ubuntu 14.10 running Flashback with Metacity.

When one issue a command like:

```
notify-send test
```

no message appear. Looking at processes the `notify-osd` is started when notify-send is executed. `kill` it and it re-appear on `notify-send`, but still no message. On occasion ot works to send using root:

```
sudo notify-send test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have not found why notify-send does not work with `notify-osd`, but looking at:

> /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service

one find

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.freedesktop.Notifications
Exec=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/notify-osd
```

Changing this to use `notification-daemon` seems to work.

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.freedesktop.Notifications
Exec=/usr/lib/notification-daemon/notification-daemon
```

So at least for now that is a hack / fix.

> org.gnome.Notifications.service

defaults to `notification-daemon`.